# Is it possible to have more than one or two strokes on an SVG single path?

Tags: svg

Is it possible to add more than one or two strokes on a single svg path.
Ex.
This is my code

```
<svg id="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="576" width="576" style="position: absolute;">
     <path d="M 10,10 L 10,20 20,20 20,10 30,10" fill="#ff0000;" stroke="#f000" stroke-width="1px" ></path>
</svg>
```

and I want stroke color like as a below image:

[image]

Comment: You could duplicate the path and use `stroke-dasharray` or some sort of linear gradient but you might end up doing much more work then simply breaking it into separate segments

Comment: @Meir it also not possible in my condition . Do you have any example of this ?

Comment: Example of dash array? Though now I suspect the white part of the dash will overlap the other strokes

Comment: @Meir I want it in a single SVG path so dash array also not working in my condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have split path and give different colors.

```
<svg id="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="576" width="576" style="position: absolute;">
   <path d="M 10,10 L 10,20" fill="#ff0000;" stroke="yellow" stroke-width="1px" ></path>
   <path d="M 10,20 L 20,20" fill="#ff0000;" stroke="red" stroke-width="1px" ></path>
   <path d="M 20,20 L 20,10" fill="#ff0000;" stroke="blue" stroke-width="1px" ></path>
   <path d="M 20,10 L 30,10" fill="#ff0000;" stroke="green" stroke-width="1px" ></path>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

One path, one stroke.
You may redraw the same path over and over using different settings of `stroke-dasharray` with different colors, so that three gaps will be followed by one segment in a specifc color. However, the length of such segments would have to coincide with the length of the line segments.
If the line segments (from corner to corner) have a differing length within the path, then this would not work.
And: the length of the line segments has to match exactly the length of th egaps specified by `stroke-dasharray`.

Edit: For aligning the length, you may explicitly set the path length within the path element using `pathLength="100"`
and combine that with `stroke-dasharray="25, 75"` and varying value of 
`stroke-dashoffset` steping through 0, 25, 50, 75

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I want it in a single SVG path so I am unable to redraw the same path over and over.